# Однокоренные слова

Tags: словообразование

Помогите подобрать однокоренные слова к: конструкция - 6 слов, отчество - 6 слов, репетиция - 7 слов, театр - 7 слов, тревога - 7 слов.

Answer (score 3):

Покажу на примере одного слова, дальше пробуйте сами. Конструкция. Образую глагол: *что делать? конструировать.* Добавляю разные приставки - *сконструировать, переконструировать.* Причастие (тут вопрос в точке зрения: некоторые считают причастие и деепричастие формой глагола) - *конструирующий*, деепричастие: *конструируя*, *сконструировав*. Как раз 6 получилось. А еще однокоренные существительные: *конструктор*. От него прилагательное  *какой? конструкторский.* Аналогично с другими словами.

Comment: Меня бы тут слово "отчество" смутило. Понятно, что этимологичеки оно производное от "отец", но не уверен, что форму "-отч-" можно приписать к тому же корню в современном языке.

Comment: А почему нет? Отчество - по имени отца...

Comment: Отцовский топор, отеческий взгляд, отецкая дочь.
> ― Я не девка, а отецкая дочь, ― бойко отвечала Охоня. (Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк. Охонины брови (1892)